# Generating pastel colors

Tags: ruby, colors

I neeed to generate random color. But I need pstel ones. Not too dark, not too bright.

I can generate colors this way:

```
color = (1..3).to_a.map{ ( c = rand(255).to_s(16) ).size < 2 ? "0#{c}" : c }.to_s
```

But it will return colors from all palette.

Comment: Ok, now reading this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
start_color = 128 # minimal color amount
total_offset = 64 # sum of individual color offsets above the minimal amount
'#' +
  [0, rand(total_offset), rand(total_offset), total_offset].sort.each_cons(2).map{|a,b|
    "%02x" % (start_color+b-a)
  }.join
```

Actually, here's tiny Sinatra app that you can play with and see the results instantly:

```
require 'sinatra'

def get_pastel start_color, total_offset
  '#' +
    [0, rand(total_offset), rand(total_offset), total_offset].sort.each_cons(2).map{|a,b|
      "%02x" % (start_color+b-a)
    }.join
end

get '/:start_color/:total_offset' do |start_color, total_offset|
  (0..20).map{c = get_pastel(start_color.to_i, total_offset.to_i)
    "<span style='background-color:#{c}'>#{c}</span>\n"
  }.join
end
```

Then fire up the browser and see how it looks:

http://localhost:4567/192/64

http://localhost:4567/128/128

;)

Answer (score 1):

This might give you something useful:

```
colour_range = 128
colour_brightness = 64
color = (1..3).to_a.map{ ( c = rand(colour_range)+colour_brightness.to_s(16) ).size < 2 ? "0#{c}" : c }.to_s
```

I think it will limit you to mid saturation, mid-brightness colours.

Comment: Ruby's Range class includes the Enumerable module meaning that your .to_a call here is redundant. /pedantry

Comment: Also, `String#%` is more suitable for outputting zero padded hex.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Guys. I was addressing the question of colour, but overlooked good style and grace.